# Using Jquery within rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use some Jquery witihin a rails application. This is my first time using Jquery in rails and I cannot seem to get it to work. I am using rails4 and this is what my code looks like

I have a pages controller with an index action

index action

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
end
```

pages.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow);
  });
});
```

index.html.erb

```
 <button class="button">Clickme</button>
```

However I get no response, am I missing something here ?

Comment: Hi. You have a `'` missing from the fadeOut method. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Rails4 uses turbolinks.

So in coffescript your code should be:

pages.js.coffee

```
ready = ->
  $('.button').click -> 
    $(this).fadeOut('slow')


$(document).ready(ready)
$(window).bind('page:change', ready)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller "pages"?  Where is "pages.js" located?

If "pages" is the controller, and "pages.js" is in /app/assets/javascripts/ then I am of no help.  But in my test app, I placed your javascript in the .js file for the controller, in /app/assets/javascripts/ and the button fades out like you expected.